# A folder of files, all with different name, moving just the ones that are different

Tags: linux, command-line

I've got a folder with about 1000 pictures in it.

Many of the pictures are the same, but have different file names.

I'm looking for a command (Mac) that will be able to identify which pictures are different and move them to another folder.

Each picture probably has 20-30 similar versions in the same folder. I'm just trying to isolate one version of it and discard the rest.

Comment: If the pictures were identical this could be pretty easy but if there are even minute differences between them or different file sizes it could get tricky.

Comment: A tool like md5sum will not look for the timestamp, but every byte makes a differnce. From the title: different files. From the text: not similiar ones. What shall we choose? And: Given the files a1 a2 b c1 c2 c3, where a1=a2 and c1=c2=c3: move those who are differentt: would we move just b or a1, c1 as well? And why a1, and not a2?

Comment: I think the files are the same. Assume they are.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the program [fdupes](http://netdial.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html) will find and list identical files in groups, e.g.

```
$ fdupes -r .
./My Pictures/Dad on boat/DadOnBoat.epp
./Pictures/My Pictures/Dad on boat/Dad on boat.epp

./My Pictures/avatar.jpg
./Pictures/My Pictures/smallavatar.jpg
```

( -r means to recurse, . is the current directory)

You may have to use whatever package management tool is on your system to find and install fdupes.

There is also an option to prompt the user to delete files, and an option to delete without prompting.